# Always got undef error of lager_transform when using lager log framework

Tags: erlang, rebar

I want to use lager as my log utility and I have orgnazied my proj as below:

```
proj\
  |
  |--lager\
  |    |--src\
  |    |--ebin\
  |    |--...
  |     
  |--logserver\
  |    |--src\
  |    |--ebin\
  |    |--rebar.config
  |    |--...
  |
  |--rebar
  |
```

However, when I try to compile logserver, I always got the following error:

D:\proj\logserver>..\rebar compile

```
==> logserver (compile)
src/logserver_app.erl:none: error in parse transform 'lager_transform': {undef,
                                             [{lager_transform,
                                               parse_transform,
                                               [[{attribute,1,file,
                                                  {"src/logserver_app.erl",1}},  
                                                  ...
```

Can anyone know the reason? Thanks!

These is some additional information:

- I am using Windows OS and using latest version of Erlang and rebar
  and lager.
- lager itself has already been compiled. We can find the     D:\proj\logserver>dir ..\lager\ebin\lager_transform.beam   (This will
  succeed)
- rebar's config file(D:\proj\logserver\rebar.config):

  ...
    {erl_opts, [{parse_transform, lager_transform}, debug_info,{d,'TEST'}, {i, "include"}, {src_dirs, ["src"]}]}.

  {lib_dirs, ["..\lager\ebin"]}.
    ...

Answer (score 6):

If you already have lager in your deps then make sure that you move lager dependency *first* in `rebar.config` so that way it will compile first. Like so:

```erlang
{deps,[
  lager,
  ..
]}.
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you add *lager* as a dependency in your `rebar.config`? I guess *lager* is not in the path.

From the [rebar wiki](https://github.com/basho/lager#usage):

> To use lager in your application, you need to define it as a rebar dep
>   or have some other way of including it in erlang’s path. You can then
>   add the following option to the erlang compiler flags:
>
> ```
> {parse_transform, lager_transform}
> ```

You can add 'lager' as a dependency by editing your `rebar.config`:

```
%% == Dependencies ==

%% Where to put any downloaded dependencies. Default is "deps"
{deps_dir, "deps"}.

%% What dependencies we have, dependencies can be of 3 forms, an application
%% name as an atom, eg. mochiweb, a name and a version (from the .app file), or
%% an application name, a version and the SCM details on how to fetch it (SCM
%% type, location and revision). Rebar currently supports git, hg, bzr and svn.
{deps, [application_name,
        {application_name, "1.0.*"},
        {application_name, "1.0.*",
         {git, "git://github.com/basho/rebar.git", {branch, "master"}}}]}.
```

In your case, that should be something like:

```
{deps, [{lager, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/basho/lager.git", "HEAD"}}]}.
```

More info about the rebar dependency manager here:

https://github.com/basho/rebar/wiki/Dependency-management

Comment: Thanks. But my lager is located in my local directory. So how can I add it as a dependency ?

Comment: Just added rebar configuration for lager.

Comment: I have been having similar issues. I have tried above suggestions with no success. see this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813513/configuring-lager-i-get-this-error-undefined-parse-transform-lager-transform

Comment: I'm total dumb with rebar3, but the foggy part for me was to catch where the "erlang compiler flags" were located according to rebar3.Turned out I had to change a line in rebar.config from this`{erl_opts, [debug_info]}.` to this `{erl_opts, [debug_info, {parse_transform, lager_transform}]}.`